# Chrome Extension doesnt work for first few times

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have just built a chrome extension. It changes the context menu using the following -

**In content script**

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
 if(event.button == 2) {
        if (isNaN(window.getSelection().toString())){
           chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "createStringMenu"});
        }
   else {
       chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "createNumberMenu"});            
    }
}

}, true);
```

**In Background**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request) {
if(request.cmd == "createStringMenu") {
    chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
        chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Send ' %s '  as SMS ", "contexts": ['selection'],"onclick": send_as_sms});
    });
} else if(request.cmd == "createNumberMenu") {
    chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
        chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Send SMS to %s ", "contexts": ["selection"],"onclick": send_sms_to});
    });
}
});
```

Whenever the extension runs for the first time either on a newly opened browser or when the extension is installed ( and web pages are refreshed) , no menu is created. then onwards, it does.

What should I do? What could be causing it?

Comment: Do you mean for the first time after extension installation or after relaunching the browser (it starts on a new tab page right?). Try to add some debug logging into both scripts to see what is called and what isn't.

Comment: I mean everytime after relaunching the browser the extension stops working for the first try.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the context menu appears before the background page can change the content of that context menu. The second time you right-clicked, background page has already changed the content in the first time you pressed, so it works in the second time.

Comment: Yaa, i guessed the same, but how should I avoid it?